# c++ how to get depth of a binary tree recursively

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I wrote a code that suposed to return the depth of a binary tree from the root to the node who called the function. using recursive way but I faced a problem about how to count the number of times that the function gets called so I whould know how much convexity I passed. Someone know how can I do that?

```
int BSNode::getDepth(const BSNode& root) const
{
    if (this != nullptr)
    {
        if (root.getData() > this->_data)
        {
            this->getDepth(*root.getRight());
        }
        else if (root.getData() < this->_data)
        {
            this->getDepth(*root.getLeft());
        }
        else if (root.getData() == this->_data)
        {
            // return the number that the function counted
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing this the wrong way round, you should not return the depth in the last iteration but instead return 1 (or 0) in the last iteration. And during recursion you get the left depth, get the right depth and return the maximum of those + 1.

Comment: I dont need the maximum depth, I need the depth between the root and the node who call the function

Comment: Ah, i See, sorry, in that case do not take the max but instead in both cases return the depth of the recursive call + 1.

Comment: Why does your `BSNode` have a depth function? Shouldn't depth function be in your BSTree class? It makes no sense for a node to have that function.

Comment: yea the class called BSNode...

Answer (score 0):

You should at least return something in *every* case. And when you arrive at the intended node (having the data you are looking for), then return 0. In all other cases, return what you get from recursion plus 1. If the value is not found then indeed -1 should be returned. And if this -1 is coming back from recursion, it should be returned like that also to the caller (without adding 1).

Here is the code adapted:

```
int BSNode::getDepth(const BSNode& root) const
{
    int temp;
    if (this != nullptr)
    {
        if (root.getData() > this->_data)
        {
            temp = this->getDepth(*root.getRight());
            return temp == -1 ? -1 : temp + 1;
        }
        else if (root.getData() < this->_data)
        {
            temp = this->getDepth(*root.getLeft());
            return temp == -1 ? -1 : temp + 1;
        }
        else if (root.getData() == this->_data)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```